# "julia-lang:This case is not supported yet"

Tags: julia

I was practicing with some exercise like [P3.jl](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/cs2101a_moreno/htmls/P3.jl). When I run following code, it hasn't any error and the answer is correct.

```
N = 10
A = rand(N,N)
SA = convert(SharedArray, A)
T = 100
Jacobi_parallel(SA,N,T)
```

But when I run with N=16386, it has an error:

> This case is not supported yet

How can i resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: this is not an error of julia. Jacobi_parallel is a function defined in the file you linked to, and the particular error is hardcoded in it. Search for the phrase "This case is not supported yet" in the page and you'll see it.  (EDIT: though, hm, the error doesn't make sense in terms of the calculations involved either. Perhaps there's an unexpected conversion to float at somepoint)

Comment: what version of julia are you using? The code seems to be for a rather older version (plus there's some 'weird stuff' in there, but, oh well) ... after fixing a couple of incompatibilities though, the script ran fine for me on the latest stable (v0.5.2). (i changed `ifloor(k/2)` to `floor(Int64, k/2)` and `error (` to `error(`  )

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou i am using version 0.5.2 too, i applied these changes but it has the previous  error:This case is not supported yet

Comment: I spotted the bug, but it _is_ a bug. I'll reply below to point out the code.

Answer (score 3):

In this part of the code:

```
@everywhere function Jacobi_blockwise_parallel_one_time_step(A,x,y,k,threshold)
  if k <= threshold
    Jacobi_serial_one_block_one_time_step(A,x,y,k)
  else
    k1 = floor(Int64, k/2)
    k2 = k - k1
    if (k1 != k2) error("This case is not supported yet") end
    lrefs = [@spawn Jacobi_blockwise_parallel_one_time_step(A,x,y,k1,threshold),
             @spawn Jacobi_blockwise_parallel_one_time_step(A,x+k1,y,k1,threshold),
             @spawn Jacobi_blockwise_parallel_one_time_step(A,x,y+k1,k1,threshold),
             @spawn Jacobi_blockwise_parallel_one_time_step(A,x+k1,y+k1,k1,threshold)];
    pmap(fetch, lrefs)
  end
end
```

When you call it the first time with k = N-2 (i.e. for N=2048 this triggers the error for me), k = 1023, and when you get to the 'spawn' statements, in the second call 'k' becomes 511 and k2 becomes 512, so this error is triggered.

Interestingly, the error does not appear if you run without adding extra worker processes first. Presumably the @spawn macro behaves differently / unexpectedly when there's no defined workers, I'm not sure. Either way though, I don't think the `lrefs` bit is doing what the author thinks it's doing (maybe it did in an older version of julia?)

Comment: i don't know it did in which version. thanks. but i need to corrected this code. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I can spot the bug, but I can't "fix it" without knowing what that function it's supposed to do, sorry. Also, I just spotted this code is only a "partial solution" for [an assignment](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/cs2101a_moreno/htmls/CS2101-A2.pdf). (That explains the presence of bugs). Basically you're expected to read and understand [this link](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node44.html) and attempt to write julia code to replicate this functionality appropriately (and you may or may not end up using the partial code provided). I can't help with homework though, sorry.